# Is this sentence correct? "I don't want to put myself in a situation when you Placed me order and I did not have the material."

Tags: grammaticality

I want to say to my client:

> I don't want to put myself in a situation when you Placed me order and I did not have the material.

Is it correct?

Comment: Can you describe the situation in a little more detail?  That might help clarify what you're looking for.  Are you describing a situation where you don't want to take more orders than your business can handle?

Comment: Hi, Kafil Ahmad, and welcome to English Language & Usage. As matters stand, you are essentially asking site visitors to proofread and correct your example sentence for you, which is not the type of task this site exists to perform. As a result, your question may be closed unless you can identify a particular problem you see in your  example sentence and ask for help with it. I suspect that the central problem is with the phrase "when you Placed me order." Please consider reworking your question to avoid its being seen as an off-topic request for proofreading. Thanks!

Comment: Kafil Ahmad, I recommend you get started with [this site](http://ell.stackexchange.com/), which should better suit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Much better would be

> I don't want to put myself in a situation where **you've placed an order**, but **I don't have** the material.

If you want to be slightly more formal, you might say

> I would prefer not to put myself in a situation where **you have placed an order**, but **I do not have** sufficient material.

My preferred construction would replace the `but` for an `and`, showing even more clearly that placing an order and not having material are *happening at the same time*:

> I don't want to put myself in a situation where **you've placed an order** and **I don't have** sufficient material.

Answer (score 0):

Instead I would use "I don't want to be (alternatively, use create) a situation in which you have placed your order and I don't have the material(s) I need" (this is applicable for near-future and present).

Comment: Can I write like this " If you placed order and I would not have material."If you placed order and I would not be able to supply see the lnk pls http://www.english247.net/english-grammar-lesson-22-conditional-sentences/

Comment: can I use conditional like this

Comment: @KafilAhmad, that doesn't read right... So `you placed` [an order] is past tense and `I would not be able` is (future) conditional. You could say `if you placed` and `I was not able to`--both past tense. Or `if you were to place` and `I did not have`. You could even say, in a different context, `I would not be able to supply that if you placed an order`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would pray to God you will never have any similar situation in your business. I meant to say you will have enough material to complete your clients' orders. And for now, let me come to the point.

> You wrote:"I don't want to put myself in a situation when you Placed
>   me order and I did not have the material."

There are so many other options to say the same thing and everyone has a different way to express their feelings and concern. Let me tell you how I would say the same sentence (being a native-English speaker)

> 1-I don't want to put myself in a situation where you place an order
>   and I am not able to complete your order or am out of material.
>
> 2- I would never put myself in a situation where my clients want to
>   place an order and I am out of stock (material).
>
> In the second sentence I am not targeting or talking to the specific
>   client but I am telling him it's for all clients and it sends him a
>   message that you don't want to break the trust of your clients.
>
> 3-I don't want to put myself in a situation where someone places an
>   order and I am not able (or capable) to complete the order on time due
>   to any unexpected issue.

There could be many other possible replacements.

Now let me tell you where you have made the mistakes or what's wrong with your sentence.

> You wrote:"I don't want to put myself in a situation when you Placed
>   me order and I did not have the material."

Let me break it in two different parts:

> I don't want to put myself in a situation (it's completely fine till
>   now),
>
> when you Placed me order and I did not have the material (it's not a
>   correct way to say because you are using the past simple tense, but
>   you are talking in the present time)
>
> We can replace them:"When you Place me an order (the present simple
>   tense)" and I did not have the material (and I don't have the material
>   (if you want to clear the air more then you can add this part) to
>   complete the order)

In simple words **you have used the past simple tense to describe a present situation, which you should have written in any present tense (which makes sense)** and trust me your mistake is a minor mistake and I am sure you will improve it soon!

Comment: I used past tense because I am imagining, studied herehttp://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/wishes-and-hypotheses